# Accessing a CVS server from an OpenShift Application (Review Board)

Tags: openshift, cvs, review-board

I have an application (Review Board) that needs to be able to access a remote CVS (concurrent versions system) server. When I attempt to use the 'cvs' command-line utility from within an OpenShift console (or internally in the Review Board application), I encounter the following error:

```
CVSROOT=:pserver:anon:anon@cvs.opengroup.org:/cvs/MSB cvs co pegasus
cvs [checkout aborted]: connect to [cvs.opengroup.org]:2401 failed: Permission denied
```

This command works properly when run from my local Fedora system. I am guessing that there is likely an SELinux AVC occurring, but I have no way to verify this in OpenShift.

Answer (score 0):

The outgoing port (2401) is blocked by an SELinux policy.  The best way to request the team to open it, and track the request, is to enter a bug with your use case:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online